# How to define xpath of button having more than one classes in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There are two buttons on HTML pop up have almost similar. Both buttons are same except for the span text nothing is different.

Can anyone please suggest, how to write the xpath of OK button?

I have wrote below xpath but system showing error as '.

**My Xpath**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/descendant::button[@class='ui-button']/span[contains(@class, 'ui-button-text') and text() = 'OK']")).click();
```

**Error**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Here is My HTML code of pop up:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable" style="height: auto; width: 350px; top: 295.5px; left: 621px; display: block; z-index: 102;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="DivExtension" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle">
         <span id="ui-id-2" class="ui-dialog-title">内線番号</span>
         <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" type="button" role="button" title="Close">
              <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
              <span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
         </button>
     </div>

     <div id="DivExtension" class="display-none ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 68px;">
          <div id="extRow" class="display-none" style="display: block;">
                <p class="form-label">
                     <label for="extension">内線番号</label>
                </p>
                <p class="form-input">
                     <input id="Extension" class="text" type="text" placeholder="Extension" value="">
                </p>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
         <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
               <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" style="height: 34px; width: 104px;" role="button">
                     <span class="ui-button-text">OK</span>
               </button>

              <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" style="height: 34px; width: 124px;" role="button">
                     <span class="ui-button-text">キヤンセル</span>
              </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending if you have multiple buttons on the page with the text OK.

If you want use multiple condition you can also use something like
//*[condition_1][condition_2]

In this case:

```
//span[@class='ui-button-text'][text()='OK']
```

or for the button:

```
//button[@class='ui-button'][.//span[contains(text(), 'OK')]]
```

For multiple classes example:

```
//button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']
```

or as you use it with contains.
Note: Make sure you are waiting for the element if needed.

For an element with multiple classes you have 2 options:

1. use @class='my_class'
   this mean to use the entire value of attribute class => my_class will be all classes, the entire string
2. use contains(@class, 'my_class')
   this option allows you to use just a part of the class attribute value => my_class could be any part of the string: ui, button, ui-button etc.

In your case, you used `button[@class='ui-button']` which is not correct since the button has `class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"`.

Comment: @lauda..Thank you very much, 3rd option works for me. I have done some modification like
//button[@class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only'][.//span[contains(text(), 'OK')]]

Comment: Nice. It should work also if you will use //button[contains(@class, 'ui-button')][.//span[contains(text(), 'OK')]]

Comment: just a curiosity , what's the wrong in my xpath? Is there need to define all button classes?

Comment: @ lauda..Thank you so much , now i understand the difference..:)

Answer (score 0):

Check these two xpath's for ok button

`//button/span[contains(text(),'OK')]`

OR

`//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button/span[contains(text(),'OK')]`